# phonegap build failing, when I upload zip file

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I built my application in legacy format and converted into zip and uploaded in phonegap build. I am keep getting the following error.

> Error - The following splash screen or icon file does not exist:
>   /images/android/icons/hdpi.png

When I check the zip, that specific file available. Not sure why it sowing something like that.

Phonegap build log looks like below.

> delete ../assets/www/js/index.js (no source)   copy  manifest.json
>   ../assets/www/manifest.json (new file)   copy 
>   precache-manifest.21c7a65208bdb1b30dbd96cf8f2b857b.js
>   ../assets/www/precache-manifest.21c7a65208bdb1b30dbd96cf8f2b857b.js
>   (new file)   copy  report.html ../assets/www/report.html (new file)
>   copy  service-worker.js ../assets/www/service-worker.js (new file)
>   Wrote out android application name "Applaud HCM" to
>   /res/values/strings.xml android-versionCode not found in config.xml.
>   Generating a code based on version in config.xml (5.0.3): 50003 Wrote
>   out Android package name "com.applaudsolutions.EmployeeCenter" to
>   /src/com/applaudsolutions/EmployeeCenter/ApplaudHCM.java Found extra
>   default icon: /images/windows/icons/icon-173.png (ignoring in favor of
>   /images/windows/icons/icon-62.png) Found extra default icon:
>   /images/icon-64.png (ignoring in favor of
>   /images/windows/icons/icon-62.png)
>
> Updating icons at ../res
>
> Error:
>   Source path does not exist: /images/android/icons/hdpi.png
>       at updatePathInternal (/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/FileUpdater.js:145:19)
>       at /cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/FileUpdater.js:223:19
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Object.updatePaths (/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/FileUpdater.js:221:33)
>       at updateIcons (/cordova/lib/prepare.js:377:17)
>       at /cordova/lib/prepare.js:49:9
>       at _fulfilled (/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
>       at /cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44

can anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I changed the file names and fixed the paths.
Make sure the file path and folder structure and filenames are exactly like the following.

```
    <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
```